# how to maintain session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a website coded in codeigniter. Currently, I am facing a problem in my login system. When a registered user successfully logins and hit the browser back button, he again redirects the user login page.

In my login controller where the login view loads, I have put a condition that  if user is already logged in, redirect him to dashboard.But after successful login,if I click the browser back button, it again redirects to login page.

My controller function where login view is loaded as :

```
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') && $this->session->userdata('logged_in') !=''){

        header('location:'. base_url().'message/inbox');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->template->load('template', 'login');
    }
```

I am new to codeigniter and don't know much about it. Anyone help me please and point out what is wrong in my code.

Thanks.

Comment: btw. this part: ` && $this->session->userdata('logged_in') !=''` is redundant.

Comment: Any problem with the session itself? Is the userdata for logged in preserved after logs in (i.e. the session value is set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button usually loads the cached version of the previous page. You problem has nothing to do with CodeIgniter.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243075/965907) about fixing your problem. Although it's not for PHP, it will show you how to set up your header properly and to delete the logged_in session variable whenever the login page is opened.

EDIT

So the headers need to be in this format:

```
header('Expires: -1'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

If you know how to fix your problem in plain PHP, the approach is the same in CodeIgniter. Just clear your session or force a redirect (whichever you prefer) while making sure the cache is set to work the right way.

Comment: Where should I use thesee Response.AddHeader ? The login controller or the method where login view loads ?

Comment: Use just PHP's `header` function, like you did for redirection, and put it in the login controller. Header should always load first, before there's any output.

Comment: should I use it in this way ?

header("Expires", "-1");
header("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma", "no-cache");

Comment: I know my problem has a very simple solution in custom php by checking the session at the top of the login page, if set , then using header, wo dont allow the login page to load again.But in codeigniter it bothered me very much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you load session in your controller constructor?

> $this->load->library('session');

Comment: Yes, session library is loaded in autoload.php

Comment: After hitting the browser back button , it redirects to login again but i relad the login page, it then redirects to user dashboard as required.

Comment: Check with some other browser, guess it's not a problem.  Login page might have been loaded from the temporary files or cache.

Comment: I checked in chrome, IE, firefox. same problem.

Answer (score 0):

use below in each **construct** of every controllers class

```
if(!$this->authentication->try_session_login()){
    redirect('manage/login');
    }
```

details of `$this->authentication->try_session_login` this line:-

```
authentication = create an libyrary function named authentication. 
                In that library define try_session_login() function.
```

use this **authentication** library for login also.

I personally use this process in my application.

Comment: Instead of library, I have used a helper function, which returns true if session is set and false otherewise. That also does not work for me here.

Comment: try to use library if possible. otherwise for Your helper function first load() it into your class then call. are You getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on browser back button the it loads the page from browser history.It will always show you the login page.Though you have putted some checking but it loads page from history.For that you need to disable browser back button.

Now if you put the code at the starting of every function like

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
{
    redirect('controller_name/function_name','refresh');
}
```

it will check the session and work accordingly.